# The environment contains invalid characters, it can only contain characters allowed in PHP class names. Symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, environment-variables, composer-php, symfony4

I migrated from symfony 3.4 to symfony 4.4

Now I have this error when I run any command:

**In Kernel.php line 478:**

> The environment ".env.test.local" contains invalid characters, it can only contain characters allowed in PHP class names.

What does this means and how I can solve this issue?

Rigt now `.env.test.local` file is empty.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve this issue? Please share your current configuration

Comment: I have tried nothing. Beacuse I dont know what this error means in the first place.

Comment: @talhaamir You are trying to accomplish the extremely difficult task of migrating to a new Symfony major version without any knowledge of Symfony?  I hate to sound discouraging but that is not going to happen.  3.4 is very old and has a different way of specifying env variables.  4.4 is newer but still somewhat out of date.  This problem very much depends on how the 3.4 project was organized and how you migrated to 4.4.  If this is a commercial project then hire someone.  Otherwise, check the docs being very careful about which version you are reading.

Comment: @Cerad what makes you think that Symfony 4.4 is "out of date"? It has been released in November 2019 as an LTS version and will receive bug fixes until 2022. Many of my customers prefer to run their applications on an LTS version to avoid running out of support with versions like Sf 5.0 (which has also been released in Nov 2019 and is already out of support!)

Comment: @NicoHaase - I did say "somewhat out of date".  Nothing wrong with targeting an LTS version.  5.1 has made some more configuration tweaks.  These sorts of questions often attract comments based wrong wrong versions.  In particular, while the answer below is probably basically correct, a 3.4 app might be relying on the old SYMFONY_APP variable and not APP_ENV.  Difficult to say without details of the upgrade process.

Answer (score 2):

You're setting the `APP_ENV` variable to `.env.test.local` (or you're executing `bin/console` with `--env=.env.test.local` flag).

The environment name should be only `test`, not `.env.test`.
Change your `APP_ENV` variable (or your `--env` flag) to `test`.

Comment: I can not seem to understand your answer.  Can you please explain this in detail or tell me which files I shoud modify for this ? 
Also I am working with XAMPP on Windows.

Comment: Check your environment variables, phpunit.xml (or xml.dist), xampp configuration and all your .env files. In one of these places you should find something like `APP_ENV=.env.test.local`. This is causing the issue you’re seeing. Change the value to `test` only